# How to run jetty as a daemon

Tags: jetty, ubuntu-12.04, jetty-9

I've just downloaded jetty 9 and wanted to run it as a daemon. I've set some options in `/etc/default/jetty`, here they are:

```
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty
JETTY_ARGS=jetty.port=8080
NO_START=0
JETTY_USER=jetty
JETTY_PID=/opt/jetty/jetty.state
JETTY_LOGS=/var/log/jetty
DEBUG=1
```

When I run `service jetty start` I get this:

```
Starting Jetty: FAILED Sun Apr 13 17:20:25 UTC 2014
```

Well, what could be wrong? There's no info in logs, how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2011/02/solr-jetty-and-daemons-debugging-jettysh) for some tips. The default script runs start-stop-daemon with the -b flag, which puts everything into a detached process and prevents output from going to the console. Remove -b and add -v (verbose), and you'll probably get some debugging information and an indication of how far it got.